# Wordpress images seem to be down

Tags: wordpress, amazon-cloudfront

A friend of mine has a Wordpress site and I help out from time to time. I went on there today and noticed that some images are not being displayed.

He has a post created and published and in that post he has this code:

```
[caption id="attachment_1173" align="alignnone" width="800"]<img class="size-full wp-image-1173" src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/335237585.jpg" alt="Image 1" width="800" height="569" /> Image caption[/caption]
```

However when I view the page the alt tag is displayed and if I inspect the element the source (src) of the image is pointing to a completely different domain:

```
http://d14x51nv4ivcb0.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/35237585.jpg
```

Which fails to load correctly.

Also at the end of the source code there is this comment:

```
<!-- Performance optimized by W3 Total Cache. Learn more: https://www.w3-edge.com/products/
Content Delivery Network via Amazon Web Services: CloudFront: d14x51nv4ivcb0.cloudfront.net
Served from: domain.com @ 2017-02-28 12:04:57 by W3 Total Cache -->
```

So it seems like the cloudfront domain/W3 Total Cache is down? I have never used W3 Total Cache before but seems strange that in the post the image src is set correctly but it gets transformed when viewed.

Comment: W3 Total Cache is probably changing the source behind the scenes? Doing a search on cloudfront reveals some evidence that they are having some problems. There must be a way in W3 total cache to turn off that image hosting feature. FYI, W3 total cache isn't down since that is a plugin that works entirely from your site. It's the integration with cloudfront that is probably having problems.

Comment: Look here: https://www.wpkube.com/set-amazon-cloudfront-w3-total-cachewp-super-cache/ It describes how to set up W3 with cloudfront. It says there is a checkbox to enable CDN. So I guess you just have to uncheck it.